# Not getting Display Configuration window on WinServer2008 Hyper VM

Tags: hyper-v

When connecting using VMConnect, I am not getting the Display Configuration window providing the option to select a screen resolution on a VM running Windows Server 2008 SP2.

The Host machine is Windows 8.1.

There is no vmconnect.rdp..config for the VM

In Hyper V Settings :

- Server : Allow enhanced session mode is marked
- User : Use enhanced session mode is marked

In the guest OS and/or its settings :

- All Integration Services are marked
- I am logging in as the local Admin
- Remote Desktop is enabled

When connecting, the Enhanced session item under the View menu is not marked.

I do receive this prompt with a Windows Server 2012 VM - here the Enhanced session item is marked.

Comment: Server 2008 doesn't allow resolution changes when RDP'd into it, as the resolution used for RDP is decided by the client. Try using the console in the Hyper-V manager instead.

Comment: I am using the console. That is the entire point.